# batch delimiter command not working

Tags: batch-file

I'm fairly new to windows batch and have ran into an issue that I can't figure out.  I writing a batch command where the user will input an IP address, 11.152.43.78 as an example, and I need to delimit the IP address so I can add or subtract numbers to the last byte.  My issue is that my batch command shuts down as soon as I enter an IP address.  I put this command together together through the examples I have found on this website.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
echo. Enter IP address of the CSR on the site.
echo. Example: 11.152.34.82
set /p IP="IP Address: "
for /F tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in ("%IP%") do echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d
pause
cls
echo. select the technology you are trying to restore
echo. 1: AWS
echo. 2: PCS
echo. 3: LTE 1
echo. 4: LTE 2
set /p w="Enter number: "
```

Comment: A quote is missing here: `for /F tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=."` (just before `tokens`), should be `for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=."`

Comment: that was it, thanks. I feel kinda foolish now.

Comment: when you say: the window closes, you should debug by running your .bat in an existing cmd window. You would have got (in french but I feel it doesn't bother you): `U:\>set /p IP="IP Address: "
IP Address: 33.44.22.33
1 était inattendu.

U:\>for /F tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %a in ("33.44.22.33") do echo %a, %b, %c, %d`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for you:

```
@Echo Off
Echo= Enter IP address of the CSR on the site.
Echo= Example: 11.152.34.82
Set/P "IPA= "
Call :Sub %IPA:.= %

Rem Your commands using new %IPA% here:
Echo= Your new IP address is %IPA%

Timeout -1 >Nul
Exit/B

:Sub
    ClS
    Echo= Select the technology you are trying to restore.
    Echo= [1] AWS
    Echo= [2] PCS
    Echo= [3] LTE 1
    Echo= [4] LTE 2
    Choice /C 1234 /N
    If ErrorLevel 4 Set "LO=73"
    If ErrorLevel 3 Set "LO=61"
    If ErrorLevel 2 Set "LO=44"
    If ErrorLevel 1 Set "LO=27"
    Set "IPA=%1.%2.%3.%LO%"
```